# Find a plane parallel to a line and perpendicular to $5x-2y+z=3$.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Find a plane parallel to the following line: $$x=3t+2, y=-t+1, z=t-1$$ and perpendicular to:
$$5x-2y+z=3.$$

I've tried the following:
The normal vector to the plane above is <5,-2,1>.
The normal/direction vector to line is <3, -1, 1>.
I did the dot product on these two normal vectors, and I got 18. Now I'm not sure where to go from here to get the equation of the plane I'm supposed to be finding.

Comment: Try and make sure you can understand the following: the plane we want contains both the normal to the second plane and the directional vector of the line. The cross product gives the normal for the first plane (ignoring any possible definitions/conventions of the length of normal), i.e., the orientation of the first/desired plane. Can you visualize that? Then we need a base point, though that seems to arbitrary as the problem is stated.

Comment: BTW, I think it is generally expected that attempts will be shown in questions here. For future reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a plane is given by $Ax + By + Cz = D$, then the direction of the vector normal to a plane is $\begin{bmatrix} A \\ B \\ C\end{bmatrix}$.

If a line is given by $x = M_1t + B_1, y = M_2t + B_2, z = M_3t + B_3$, then the direction of the line is $\begin{bmatrix} M_1 \\ M_2 \\ M_3\end{bmatrix}$

A line is parallel to a plane (I'm assuming this is what you mean) if it never intersects the plane or always intersects the plane.  That means that the normal vector of the plane and the direction of the line are perpendicular.

Two vectors, $\begin{bmatrix} x_1 \\ y_1 \\ z_1\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} x_2 \\ y_2 \\ z_2\end{bmatrix}$, are perpendicular if and only if $x_1x_2 + y_1y_2 + z_1z_2 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you! This great @DanielV!